# Is it possible to place images and videos on sides of moving geometric figures in Blender?

Tags: animation

Here is the example of animation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekWu57GI38I&t=271

From 4:31 till 4:38. Animated background. Infographics over it. I focuse the attention on animated background. There are geometric figures. Parallelepipeds. They move. I want to make similar animated background. Not one to one to this. I will use other colors, other sizes, other direction of move.

I will make parallelepipeds. They will move. Slowly.

On sides of few parallelepipeds I want to place still images. Parallelepipeds will move. On sides of few other parallelepipeds I want to place videos. Parallelepipeds will move, videos on sides will go. Is it possible to make in Blender?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Try it.

Comment: @susu Thank you, susu. Which render engine to use in this case? Eevee? Cycles?

Comment: again... try and find out what works for you.